# Amazon Lambda Java Function not insert data to DynamoDB

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Currently I am working with **Amazon Webservices.**

I create one Java lambda function using `Eclipse IDE`.

After created function in eclipse I test function eclipse using **JUnit Test**.

Lambda function execute successfully and also inserted data successfully to `DynamoDB`.

**But problem is :**

I run function on lambda from Eclipse using **Run Function on AWS Lambda** functionality.

Data is not inserting and its throwing exception.

I also test this method using `API Gateway` but get same exception.

**Exception :** `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS credential profiles file not found in the given path: /home/sbx_user1051/.aws/credentials`

Please Friends Help me to solve this problem.

> NOTE : I already added full permission for both Lambda Function and
>   DynamoDB.

I am using below code to insert Data to `DynamoDB`.

```
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider("my_default_profile")));

Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(TABLE_NAME);

String login_id = (String) inputHashMap.get("login_id");
String password = (String) inputHashMap.get("password");
String type = (String) inputHashMap.get("type");
String device_id = (String) inputHashMap.get("device_id");

try {
    Exception eItem item = new Item().withPrimaryKey("login_id", login_id)
        .withString("device_id", device_id)
        .withBoolean("isUserVerified", false)
        .withString("password", password)
        .withString("type", type);

    table.putItem(item);
}
catch(Exception e){

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try creating the DynamoDB object without a profile.

`DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient());`

Comment: I already added full permission for both Lambda Function and DynamoDB.

Comment: Ok Wait I will be back after create object as you mansion above.

Comment: Its Work. But can you tell me one more thing.? If I use only  `DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient());` Will Any problem arise?

Comment: Now I m getting this exception : `com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain`

Comment: Do you have your local credentials located at ~/.aws/credentials ? You can set them by installing awscli and running aws configure

Comment: Ya I have credentials at /.aws/credentials.

Comment: Now I solved problem. Problem was I change profile name default to other   name. So That was the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the Help.